# iPhone UITabBarController

Tags: iphone, core-animation, uiimageview, uitabbarcontroller

I am using a UITabBarController with 3 items and am curious how to access a method from the first tab if I am on the second or third tab. The problem I am running into is I have a UIImageView on the first tab that is using core animation to loop continuously through 3 images. But when I switch to the second tab and try to switch back to the first tab the program hangs. I discovered if I stop the animation then it will let me switch back to the first tab fine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access view controllers in UITabBarController using its `viewControllers` property (returns array of controllers) and get the one you need by its index.
The better way, however, is to try to stop animations in controller's `-viewWillDisappear:` method and resume animations in `-viewWillAppear:` .

Comment: thanks, using the viewWillAppear and viewWillDisappear methods to stop and start the animation worked perfectly.